# UITextField inside UIView doesn't size properly in XIB file when setting font size

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UITextField wrapped in a UIView, made into a custom class. It works fine in a ViewController (storyboard), but when used inside a UIView that is in a XIB file, the behaviour is the following:

If I set the font size to anything below 17, the expected height is 0pt.

If I set the font size to 17, expected height is correct (~20something units).

If I set the font size to anything above 17, the expected height is 4000pt.

The code in question:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

@IBDesignable class AppleBug: UIView {

    // Interface builder values
    @IBInspectable var placeholderText: String = "" {
        didSet { updateUI() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var textSize: CGFloat = 14 {
        didSet { updateUI() }
    }

    // Views
    lazy var textField = UITextField()

    // MARK: Initialization
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupTextField()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupTextField()
    }

    // MARK: View setup
    private func setupTextField() {
        addSubview(textField)
        textField.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.edges.equalTo(self)
        }
    }

    // MARK: View updating
    private func updateUI() {
        textField.placeholder = placeholderText
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(textSize)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for the custom view so the issue clear?

Comment: Yup, I added the code.